# How an i design Schema for Categories and sub Categories using mongodb(mongoose schema)?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, meanjs, mongoose-schema

I am new to mongodb i want to create Categories with sub Categories Schema.for example Categories is nokia .in nokia lot of models is there for this how can i design Schema pls some one help me out.

Example:

```
Categories :nokia
sub Categories :Nokia Lumia 730,Nokia 225,Nokia Lumia 1020,Nokia Lumia 530
```

my SCHEMA:

```
 var ShopSchema = new Schema({

    Email: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,

    },
    Storename: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    Type: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    Categories: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    }


});
```

Comment: Since MongoDB is non-relation data model, please elaborate user requirements and use cases. It would help us to propose right schema structure.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/category-hierarchy/ which has an example of using categories in mongodb, and it explains the schemas and the most common operations.

Comment: an you pls add example for tis